# Python IMAP: Cannot mark email as seen

Tags: python, imap, imaplib

I'm trying to set an email as read using the Python IMAP library. Just like in this example:
[Python, IMAP and GMail. Mark messages as SEEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251977/python-imap-and-gmail-mark-messages-as-seen)

I select a GMail account's "All email" folder then obtain the UID of a specific email through the search command. Then I use that UID to try and mark it as read, but fail.

```
    result, data = mail.uid('fetch', email_uid, '(FLAGS)')

    print "RESULT: ",result,data

    mail.select(folder_name, readonly=False)
    result, data = mail.store(email_uid, '+FLAGS', '\\Seen')

    print "RESULT OF OPERATION FOR UID",email_uid,result,data
```

No matter how many times I run this piece of code I always obtain the flags not containing the \Seen flag.

Sample execution (ignore Django prints):

```
FINAL QUERY: (SENTSINCE 07-Mar-2013 SENTBEFORE 11-Mar-2013 LARGER 7508 SMALLER 7510)
RESULT:  OK ['31424 (UID 54264 FLAGS (NotJunk $NotJunk))']
RESULT OF OPERATION FOR UID 54264 OK [None]

[09/Mar/2013 17:30:37] "GET /api/mark_as_read/320/?token=8e3c057b841b75c864685786b2a9657aadf17e3bfb991b103b7c4b3ffdd2a753&refresh_mode=all&folder_mode=inbox HTTP/1.1" 200 144
FINAL QUERY: (SENTSINCE 07-Mar-2013 SENTBEFORE 11-Mar-2013 LARGER 7508 SMALLER 7510)
RESULT:  OK ['31424 (UID 54264 FLAGS (NotJunk $NotJunk))']
RESULT OF OPERATION FOR UID 54264 OK [None]

[09/Mar/2013 17:30:44] "GET /api/mark_as_read/320/?token=8e3c057b841b75c864685786b2a9657aadf17e3bfb991b103b7c4b3ffdd2a753&refresh_mode=all&folder_mode=inbox HTTP/1.1" 200 144
FINAL QUERY: (SENTSINCE 07-Mar-2013 SENTBEFORE 11-Mar-2013 LARGER 7508 SMALLER 7510)
RESULT:  OK ['31424 (UID 54264 FLAGS (NotJunk $NotJunk \\Seen))']
RESULT OF OPERATION FOR UID 54264 OK [None]
```

I tried multiple variations. I tried setting the flag \Seen, Seen, \Seen, SEEN, with parenthesis, without parenthesis, and have no idea what I might try apart from this.

I suspect there might be some very specific detail here - maybe the GMail "All email" folder does not allow to mark an email as read?

I also don't know if, in the (result,data) tuple returned in the mail.store command, if the data variable is supposed to have the "[None]" variable for a normal execution, or if it means that something is wrong.

If I try to set a wrong flag like \\Seen the mail.store command raises an error. So when setting the \Seen flag it is a valid IMAP flag.

I have no idea what to try next.

Any help would be very appreiated.

Comment: `RESULT:  OK ['31424 (UID 54264 FLAGS (NotJunk $NotJunk \\Seen))']`  Does that not show the Seen flag been set?

Comment: You are correct, in this instance it did mark the email as seen, but it does not always behave as intended. The prints are very irregular.

Comment: I don't know if you got your code working properly but I just run into this yesterday when I tried to set a FLAG through UID. The only way I got it to work is when I set it through sequential ids. Anyways let us know if you got it working thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [IMAP specification for the STORE command](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2060.html#section-6.4.6) does not have an option to set flags by UID.  You can only set them (like in the example you linked to) by `message set`.
The only reason it works *sometimes* is that the sequences for your UID's and message set's are relatively close (`31424` vs `54264`).

```
RESULT:  OK ['31424 (UID 54264 FLAGS (NotJunk $NotJunk))']
```

You're not actually **ever** setting the flags by `UID`, you're setting them by `message set`...which occasionally corresponds to a `UID`.

---

You **can** set flags by `UID` however (just not with a `STORE` command).  You can issue an [UID Command](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.4.8) with the first argument being `store` to set flags:

```
result, data = mail.uid('store', '542648', '+FLAGS', '(\\Seen)')
```

If successful, the server will respond with the `message set` corresponding to the UID you used -eg (using your example):

```
OK ['31424 (FLAGS (\\Seen))']
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use my package:
https://pypi.org/project/imap-tools/

```
with MailBox('imap.mail.com').login('test@mail.com', 'pwd', 'INBOX') as mailbox:

    # SEEN: mark all messages sent at 05.03.2007 in current folder as unseen, *in bulk
    mailbox.seen(mailbox.uids("SENTON 05-Mar-2007"), False)
```

Comment: @YaroslavNikitenko, You may use ->my package