# python open mail vs read mail

Tags: python, email, gmail

I try to open mails on gmail.
I have the following code but it actually reads the mail on the console.
I would like gmail detects the mail has been opened, because when I run the script on the console, the mail is not really opened. It is still in bold in my gmail.

```
import imaplib, email

user = 'xxx@gmail.com'
password = 'xxx'
imap_url = 'imap.gmail.com'

def get_body(msg):
    if msg.is_multipart():
        return get_body(msg.get_payload(0))
    else:
        return msg.get_payload(None,True)

con = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_url)
con.login(user,password)
con.select('INBOX')



result, data = con.fetch(b'3','(RFC822)')
raw = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])
print(get_body(raw))
```

if I mark message as seen, the message will look like I have read it but gmail or the sender of the message know I won't have read it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python, IMAP and GMail. Mark messages as SEEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251977/python-imap-and-gmail-mark-messages-as-seen)

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the problem here [Python, IMAP and GMail. Mark messages as SEEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251977/python-imap-and-gmail-mark-messages-as-seen)

Give this a try

```
 result.store(data[0].replace(' ',','),'+FLAGS','\Seen')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for you answer, this is not really the same because if I mark message as seen, the message will look like I have read it but gmail or the sender of the message know I won't have read it